# After the kernel and file system compiled by buildroot are started, buildroot will output log again. Where is it closed

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, buildroot

I use buildroot compiled zimage and rootfs,Running on the board can run normally, however buildroot Will output it for me again log,It's a little messy.Does anyone know where to close?

```
insmod sr501_drv.ko --> The command entered

sr501_init --> 144 --> kernel printk Printed  
Jan 1 00:38:18 buildroot user.warn kernel: sr501_init --> 144 -->buildroot Output it again  
sr501_probe --> 99 --> kernel printk Printed  
sr501_probe --> 109 --> kernel printk Printed  
Jan 1 00:38:18 buildroot user.warn kernel: sr501_probe --> 99 -->buildroot Output it again  
Jan 1 00:38:18 buildroot user.warn kernel: sr501_probe --> 109 --> buildroot Output it again
```

I tried changing the kernel print level

```
echo 4 >/proc/sys/kernel/printk
```

If I change the kernel print level to 4, the kernel itself does not output, but buildroot will output for me. It goes like this:

```
insmod sr501_drv.ko

Jan 1 00:38:18 buildroot user.warn kernel: sr501_init --> 144  
Jan 1 00:38:18 buildroot user.warn kernel: sr501_probe --> 99  
Jan 1 00:38:18 buildroot user.warn kernel: sr501_probe --> 109
```

But I want our normal kernel output to look like this:

```
insmod sr501_drv.ko

sr501_init --> 144  
sr501_probe --> 99  
sr501_probe --> 109
```

Comment: I have the same issue when the image file was smaller than necessary to keep full `initramfs` archive on it. It cut me a few binaries at the end of image (basically something from /usr/sbin/) and provokes the same behaviour. If it's not the case, you have to look into rsyslog and similar modules you have, it's their responsibility to print all that stuff.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. I have checked it and it is output by syslog.  I just deleted the /etc/init. d/s01syslog file.  Thank you very much

Comment: I hope you understand that what you did is a hack and not a solution :-) Good luck!